# Univariate outlier detection

Tags: r, statistics, regression, outliers

This time I won't be asking a direct question on how to detect outliers as I did before in one of my questions. I did read some posts related to this topic but didn't get what I needed. I have a set of values which are given below:

```
y<-c(0.59, 0.61, 0.59, 1.55, 1.33, 3.50, 1.00, 1.22, 2.50, 3.00, 3.79, 3.98, 4.33, 4.45, 4.59, 4.72, 4.82, 4.90, 4.96, 7.92, 5.01, 5.01, 4.94, 5.05, 5.04, 5.03, 5.06, 5.10, 5.04, 5.06, 7.77, 5.07, 5.08, 5.08, 5.12, 5.12, 5.08, 5.17, 5.18)
```

Now as most of the researchers say that the outlier detection process not only depends on the data but also on the context. I have used several packages from R like outliers (grubbs test), extremevalues, mvoutlier(pcout method) but couldn't find out the best way to use them. Here in this case (depending on my requirements), 7.77 (obs no 31), 7.92 (obs on 20), and 3.50 (obs no 6) are outliers. Using outliers package's grubbs test I can detect 7.77 and 7.92 as outliers but not 3.50. I don't know whether I can post my plot of data here or not but after viewing the trend of the data on the plot or the distribution, observation No 6 would be obvious as an outlier.

I am trying to fit a non linear model to this data but because of these outliers, I couldn't find the best fit (best fit is not the only requirement) and anyway I need to detect these outliers as I will be fitting a separate model on these outliers.

My question is very simple. Is it possible that I can some how detect these 3 outliers with some standard package OR how can I use my non linear generated model to aid in detecting these outliers?

Best regards

Shahzad

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using rlm in the MASS package to do a robust linear regression instead?

Comment: @tcash21 Yes I have used it and its a linear regression. I have also nlrob (robust non-linear regression) but couldn't find a way to detect the said outliers with the generated model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(TSA)
ar = TSA::arima(y, c(1,0,0))
detectAO(ar)
```

shows exactly these 3 points (`ind` is indices of possible outliers):

```
> detectAO(ar)
            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
ind     6.000000 20.000000 31.000000
lambda2 4.739695  5.957604  5.490739
```

But be careful to apply this approach to any kind of data.

Comment: Thanks. Does regular arima order (as here 1,0,0) depends on the data?

Comment: I mean you should understand the nature of your data.

Comment: For instance: `auto.arima()` function from `forecast` library conducts search for best ARIMA model in class of models. But using such estimation you will not be able to detect outliers as far as these points will be treated as typical data which should be fitted with model, but not outliers.

Answer (score 5):

Just to say that I tried using `detectAO()` as suggested above and it didn't find anything with my data (which looked somewhat similar: short spikes coming off a continuous trend). After googling around, I found that the Hempel filter (function `hempel()` from package `pracma`) could do what I needed. I thought I'd add this here in case someone else is looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("forecast")         
library(forecast)
tsoutliers(data)
```

These three codes in R will answer your question. After that `tsclean(data)` will clean your data.

Steps are as follows:

```
install.packages("forecast")
library(forecast)
t_s<- ts(y)
plot(t_s)
tsoutliers(t_s)
t_s_new<-tsclean(t_s)
plot(t_s_new)
```

If still problem exists, get back to me. I will provide more sophisticated outlier detector.

Comment: You should elaborate and explain more your answers